# Launcher Activity not launched from recent Apps

Tags: android, android-activity, android-memory, android-task

Suppose there are two Activities :
1. **Activity A** (Launcher Activity)
2. **Activity B**

---

When Launching **Activity B** from **Activity A**, I finish the **Activity A**.

```
startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class));
finish();
```

---

and If exit button clicked from **Activity B**, the **Activity B** get finished.

```
ExitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

---

So, suppose **Activity B** get launched from **Activity A**, and I get exit from **Activity B** (or exit from Application). There are 2 option, from where the application get launched :
1. From launcher icon
2. From Recent Apps

Now, If the application launched from **launcher icon** , then **Activity A** get launched. But If the application launched from **Recent Apps**, then **Activity B** get launched.

---

I think, **Activity B** remains in stack, even if the I call **finish()** for it.
My Question is : How can I clear the stack, when application get exit ? Tested in Android 2.3.6 version

Comment: Simple answer: you can't. That's an Android design and there are several questions and answers in Stackoverflow regarding this issue. There are some strange solutions but none of them is really always working or 100% API conform.

Comment: I think you start activity B from Activity A directly without any input and also close activity A so when you launch app from recent it may look like activity B will shown directly instead activity A.

Comment: Another solution could be use of fragments, inside onCreate() set your default fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" attribute for you MainActivity in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  I think this is the most convenient way to meet your demand.

I just tested and found this only works when you exit the app and launch the app from the app drawer(NOT long press on HOME and select the app).

If you want to always bring the root activity to the front, no matter when you re-launch the app or from the recent screen. You can declare "android:launchMode="singleTask" for the root activity, here, the MainActivity.

Comment: I can't use this tag "clearTaskOnLaunch", every time I re-launch the application, it removes all the back activities. I need to handle only a case for Recent Apps. Thanks for reply :)

Comment: it is not working...i have two activity A and B... i launched activity A(not my launcher Activity) from push notification and from there i go to activity B and finishes Activity A and then i backpressed on activity A. the app got exited as it should be because activity A is already finished. and when user open the app from recents tasks activity B open but i have already backpressed the Activity B so there should not be any activity in the activity hence my splashscrreen should open... help me

Answer (score 1):

Beside my above mentioned solution of using fragments , you can also try writing `android:excludeFromRecents` for your activity in AndroidManifest

> **android:excludeFromRecents**
>
> Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded
>   from the list of recently used applications, the overview screen. That
>   is, when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this
>   attribute determines whether the task should not appear in the list of
>   recent apps. Set "true" if the task should be excluded from the list;
>   set "false" if it should be included. The default value is "false"

**Edit**

If you follow the above it may be that your MainActivity also disappears from Recent Activity as by default all the activities of an application have the same affinity.To specify a different task use `android:taskAffinity` for which the docs says

> **android:taskAffinity**
>
> The task that the activity has an affinity for. Activities with the
>   same affinity conceptually belong to the same task (to the same
>   "application" from the user's perspective). The affinity of a task is
>   determined by the affinity of its root activity.
>
> The affinity determines two things — the task that the activity is
>   re-parented to (see the allowTaskReparenting attribute) and the task
>   that will house the activity when it is launched with the
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
>
> By default, all activities in an application have the same affinity.
>   You can set this attribute to group them differently, and even place
>   activities defined in different applications within the same task. To
>   specify that the activity does not have an affinity for any task, set
>   it to an empty string.
>
> If this attribute is not set, the activity inherits the affinity set
>   for the application (see the  element's taskAffinity
>   attribute). The name of the default affinity for an application is the
>   package name set by the  element.

Comment: This is not the perfect solution, as I am removing the application from recent apps. Also I have use to tag for other Activities.
Also I don't go with fragment, I want to keep my code short and clean. Thanks for reply :)